# "class not found" error in PHP with double-slashes (\\)

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm developing in a system in php that uses namespaces.

I have the following code (summarized, obviously)....
a class in one location with directory Foo\Bar\fubar.php

```
<?php 
namespace Foo\Bar;
class fubar
{...
```

And I have in my other .php...

```
<?php
use Foo\Bar;
use Foo\Bar\fubar;

class adventurer{
    $doomChickens = new fubar();
}
```

Now, when I check my error log, I get...

> PHP Fatal Error: Class 'Foo\\Bar\\fubar' not found.

I'm a maintainer, not original author, but in general, I'm the type to use includes & requires rather than namespaces.

What kind of error might cause the double-slashes? Is that likely the source of my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not an error, it's just how PHP prints it out. As you probably know, there are escape sequences for strings like `\n` for new line and `\t` for a tab. Well, `\\` is the escape sequence for `\`.

PHP also interprets invalid escape sequences literally, so `Foo\Bar` would be just that because `\B` is not a valid escape sequence.

For reference, the escape sequences are only parsed in double quoted strings, not single quoted ones.

---

As for solving your actual problem, you need to either explicitly `include` or `require` the file with the class or use [an autoloader](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php). The most common ones are the [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) and [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) autloaders.

By the way, the `use Foo\Bar;` line is unnecessary.

The first solution would look like this:

```
<?php
require 'path/to/other/class.php';

use Foo\Bar\fubar;

class adventurer{
    $doomChickens = new fubar();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't expect it'd display escape slashes in the actual output. I was basing this code off of existing parallels... my guess is they're probably using the autoloader route which means I now need to hunt down it's location. You saved me a lot of headscratching! Thanks!

Comment: If you're not on windows, watch out for case sensitivity. If you use a class as `Foo\bar\Baz`, PHP will look for just that, and miss `Foo\Bar\Baz`.